# mobile embedded camera in html using Apache Cordova

Tags: android, ios, mobile, camera, cordova

I'm developing a mobile app using Apache Cordova's API and would like to know if there's a way I could get the camera to work embedded on my application.

I know Apache Cordova has a camera function but it just goes to the native camera app. I wanted it to show the camera feed on the html.

Answer (score 0):

For [accessing the device camera](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/accessing-the-device-camera-with-getusermedia) I think you can use the [HTML5 getUserMedia function](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/), but as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=getUserMedia) this isn't very well supported by mobile browsers.